# Email only one tab as PDF using google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to build a simple script to email one single tab but though the script works, It keeps emailing the whole document (all the tabs), any help is appreciated.

---

```html
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   ui.createMenu('Management')
   .addItem('Performance Card', 'emailcard')
           
                  .addToUi();
}

//READY FOR AUDIT//

function emailcard() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ssID = spreadsheet.getId();
  var sheetgId = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  
  var email = spreadsheet.getRange("E6").getValues();;
  var recipientsCC = "emai@email.com"
  var agent = spreadsheet.getRange("E5").getValues(); 
  var subject = "Weekly Performance Card for - " + agent;
  var body = "Hi, <br> " + "<br>" + "Please  find your weekly performance card attached. <br> " + "<br>"+  "Let me know if you have any questions, <br>"+"<br>"+"Thank you!" + "<br>";
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).getAs("application/pdf");

  blob.setName(spreadsheet.getName() + ".pdf");


  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body,    {
      htmlBody: body,
      cc: recipientsCC,
            attachments:[blob]     
    });  
}
```